What is the most simple way to label a data.table frequency chart in R?
I'm curious as to what the easiest way to label a data.table frequency table is. For example, say I have a data.table (dt1) with the following column (animals) being c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
and I use:
dt2 <- dt1[, .N ,by = animals]

to get a frequency table (dt2):
animals N
1: 1 2
2: 2 4
3: 3 6

what's the most elegant way to label (rename) the animal column if
1 = turtle
2 = horse
3 = cat
4 = dog

This is easy to do by reference if there is no 4/dog:
dt2[animals == c(1:3), animalnames := c("turtle", "horse", "cat")]

However, this presents two issues:

it creates a new column meaning the "animals" column needs to be
dealt with, not a big deal, but it would be nice to have a more
elegant solution
the inclusion of "dog", an element that doesn't exist in the
"animals" column causes an error:

dt2[animals == c(1:4), animalnames := c("turtle", "horse", "cat", "dog")]

Error in .prepareFastSubset(isub = isub, x = x, enclos = parent.frame(),  : 
  RHS of == is length 4 which is not 1 or nrow (3). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS). Consider %in% instead.

What's the simplest solution if you:
a) Want to relabel the "animals" column
b) want to be able to use a list of possible labels that can, but may not exist in a given sample (i.e. another sample might contain dog, and another might not contain cat, but I want to use the same code for all samples)
Thanks!

You could use fcase:
dt2[,animals := fcase( animals == 1, 'turtle',
                       animals == 2, 'horse',
                       animals == 3, 'cat',
                       animals == 4, 'dog',
                       rep(TRUE,.N), 'unknown')]
dt2

#   animals     N
#    <char> <int>
#1:  turtle     2
#2:   horse     4
#3:     cat     6


There are a lot of good answers in this thread, but this is the most concise answer - It essentially solves the question in one line of code, without creating any ancillary objects.

If you have the animal names in a vector (like in your animalnames := c("turtle", "horse", "cat") code in the question), you could tweak your attempt with:
annms <- c("turtle", "horse", "cat", "dog")

dt1[, .N, by = animals][, animals := annms[animals]]

Output:
#    animals     N
#     <char> <int>
# 1:  turtle     2
# 2:   horse     4
# 3:     cat     6


I'd use, for code readability and maintanability, a new data.table with the names of the animals, and would do a join:
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(animals = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))

# make a new dt with the names of animals. This helps readability,
# and error identification and correction
anms = data.table(animals = 1:4, names = c("turtle", "horse", "cat", "dog"))

# join both tables (remember that the one "inside" is the one that
# will keep all records!) and count by names:
anms[dt1, on = "animals"][, .N, by = names]

    names     N
   <char> <int>
1: turtle     2
2:  horse     4
3:    cat     6


Not sure how efficient the solution can be, but it could be a light code if you try table within .()
> dt1 <- data.table(animals = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3))

> nms <- c("turtle", "horse", "cat", "dog")

> dt1[, .(table(animals = nms[animals]))]
   animals     N
    <char> <int>
1:     cat     6
2:   horse     4
3:  turtle     2

